# How can I format this variable to be convertable to unix timestamp?

Tags: php

I have a variable that I am grabbing from an XML so I can store it in a database table, but the format given is not being accepted by the "date()" function. Specifically the error says: "date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given". So how do I format the below example variable value to work in the date() function?

```
Sat, 19 Nov 2005 08:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: -1: This is not about the contents of the string; the error message quite clearly tells you that you're passing an _object_ rather than a _long_. So, for starters, you probably have your argument order backwards, and you're not passing the right type. _Until you show a testcase that actually demonstrates the issue_, all I can do is invite you to read the documentation for `date()` (which doesn't parse dates..)

Answer (score 6):

`date()` converts a timestamp to a string format.  You are doing the opposite of that.  You want to use `strtotime()` instead.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
echo strtotime('Sat, 19 Nov 2005 08:00:00 GMT');  // prints 1132387200
```

You can store that timestamp in a database or wherever.  You can use `date()` to reverse the process.

```
echo date(DATE_RFC822, 1132387200);  //prints 'Sat, 19 Nov 05 08:00:00 +0000'
```

Comment: There are more then 12 years since my first PHP script, but it's the first time I hear about predefined date constants. Shame on me and +1 for you.